# Rails & Devise: Logout and login not working on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app using devise and login/logout works fine live but I can't seem to logout or login on localhost.

I had changed session_store.rb so that sessions would be shared across subdomains:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: :all, tld_length: 2
```

Can you see anything that would be preventing me from logging out and logging in locally?

in config/routes:

```
 as :user do
    get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

in view:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'Signup', "#", :class => "modal-link", :data=>{toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal"} %></li>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Did you ever find out why? The answers below didn't work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've the same configuration here and my logout works fine.

Check if you logout button has the `method: :delete` as an option.

eg:

```
link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

Comment: See my edits. I also realized I can't login either (after clearing cookies). So basically it seems like no session data is persisting

Answer (score 0):

Once I had this problem and realize I didn't have this line:

`//= require jquery_ujs`

on my `application.js` (or any other JS file my page require)